# How to show saved credit cards for particular customer during transaction on basis of customer id in braintree?

Tags: javascript, java, paypal, braintree

`Braintree` payments:How to show saved credit card for particular customer during transaction on basis of customer id in `braintree`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got Answer from Braintree support and it works:
If you’re using the Drop-In UI, you’d only need to pass a customer_id along with a ClientToken.generate() API request to pull their saved payment methods. If you’re using a more integration such as hosted fields, you would need to look at running a Customer.find() API request, pass in a customer_id and then you’d receive a Customer response object that contains their previously used payment methods.

Comment: Braintree Drop-In UI does not show CVV field. could suggest me

Comment: In your braintreepayment account click settings->processing-> CVV edit and then check mark all boxes  and save